# How do I retrieve all (and only) class variables?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to extract all class variables. But my code returns all variables, including variables declared in methods (locals). For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        int z = 0;
    }
}
```

I need to get only `x` and `y` but I get `x`, `y`, and `z`.
My code so far:

```
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(content);
IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> nodes = ((CompilationUnitSyntax) tree.GetRoot()).DescendantNodes();

List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> classDeclarationList = nodes
    .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();

classDeclarationList.ForEach(cls =>
{
    List<MemberDeclarationSyntax> memberDeclarationSyntax = cls.Members.ToList();
    memberDeclarationSyntax.ForEach(x =>
    {
        //contains all variables
        List<VariableDeclarationSyntax> variables = x.DescendantNodes()
           .OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should filter for `FieldDeclarationSyntax` which, evidently, only refers to fields (also known as class variables).

I'm not sure why you're going through the extra hoop of `MemberDeclarationSyntax` though: `cls.DescendantNodes().OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>()` should work just fine since you're still going to traverse the tree anyway.

Afterwards, `FieldDeclarationSyntax.Declaration` holds what you're interested in: the `VariableDeclarationSyntax`.